# Spring State-Machine additional thread when using timers

Tags: java, spring, timer, spring-statemachine

I'm using spring state-machine in a java application. To move between states we should use some events (called them Timer Event). It seems a thread is in charge to managing the timers that is set to determine when a movement between states will be occurred (definitely the state-machine will decide based on timers if nothing happen in a state that we are in).  After adding a timer event to a transition (using Papyrus for defining state-machine), I see a remaining live thread even after main method completes. I have two questions; first, what is this thread (I mean, this thread is the same one that manages timer), and second, how can i terminate the thread at the end of my work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timers are scheduled via Spring `TaskScheduler` and with annotation based JavaConfig default instance of `ConcurrentTaskScheduler` is created. This is done in [StateMachineCommonConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/blob/master/spring-statemachine-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/statemachine/config/configuration/StateMachineCommonConfiguration.java)

If you want to modify this you can provide your own `TaskScheduler` either by overriding bean with name `taskScheduler` of use other machine configuration methods to set it. Default `ConcurrentTaskScheduler` indeed is a based on single-thread executor which is what you see. These are discussed more in a Spring Framework documentation.

Comment: If I use default ConcurrentTaskScheduler, I will have one thread per each instance of state-machine or one thread for scheduling all state machine instances?